# What is the Error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" in iOS 5?

Tags: ios

I am working on a Google Map Application. But from yesterday i am facing a problem. My app is ruining successfully on iPhone 4, 4s but not running on 5, 5S, 5C. i share my error screen shot please check.

[image]

Its showing **ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

How can i avoid this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your **Deployment Target** **3.0** to **6.0**

See this screenshot.

[image]

make it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Target, Then choose General & expand Deployment Info then Change your Deployment Target 3.0 to 7.0